# Xna ModelBones - How to move them away from eachother?

Tags: vector, 3d, matrix, xna

Hello I know that one can get absolute transforms of bones in a model.. But how to move them away (like inflating) ? I think to do so, I need to move them forward to their local positions but what I have is the absolute transfoms by

```
Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(ModelAllTransforms);
```

How to proceed further ? I mean I can use

```
mesh.ParentBone.Transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(?) * ModelAllTransforms;
```

but what would be the ? sign ..

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Vector3 vec = (Vector3)mesh.BoundingSphere.Center;

I think using central location of the boundingsphere of the mesh would give me the direction i need..

    vec.Normalize();

and move on that direction....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction you're looking for is basically the local bone's absolute transform minus the center, then normalized.

Something like this:

```
//"time" is your timing value, "speed" is some float value
Vector3 direction = bone.Translation - center;
direction.Normalize();
Vector3 translate = time * speed * direction;
bone.Translation += translate;
```

Comment: My mistake, you need the bone's translation there. Fixed.